# JSF primafaces- ajax call twice after delete filtering

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

we have app that uses wildfly and ui using jsf primafaces version 6.2
when I test the app with below scenario, primafaces- call ajax twice

1. type filtering by name
   [filter by name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsvi7.png)

   ```
   <h:form id="accountForm">
       <p:dataTable scrollable="true" value="#{accountViewController.accountReportTable}" lazy="true" var="balance" rows="20"
                    paginator="true" paginatorPosition="#{web.tablePaginatorPosition}">
           <p:column style="width:16px">
               <p:rowToggler />
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Account Number" sortBy="#{balance.accountId}" filterBy="#{balance.accountId}">
               <h:outputText value="#{balance.accountId}" />
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Account Name" sortBy="#{balance.name}" filterBy="#{balance.name}">
               <h:outputText value="#{balance.name}" />
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Account Balance" sortBy="#{balance.balance}">
               <h:outputText value="#{balance.balance}" styleClass="align-right">
                   <f:convertNumber pattern="#{web.decimalFormatCcy}" locale="#{web.locale}" />
               </h:outputText>
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Account Type" sortBy="#{balance.accountTypeName}" filterBy="#{balance.accountTypeName}">
               <h:outputText value="#{balance.accountTypeName}" />
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Group ID" sortBy="#{balance.accountGroupId}" filterBy="#{balance.accountGroupId}">
               <h:outputText value="#{balance.accountGroupId}" />
           </p:column>
           <p:column headerText="Status" sortBy="#{balance.accountStatus}" filterBy="#{balance.accountStatus}"
                     filterOptions="#{accountStatusSelect.accountStatusList}">
               <h:outputText value="#{balance.accountStatus}" />
           </p:column>
           <p:rowExpansion>
               <p:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="table-detail-label,table-detail-separator,table-detail-value" 
                            styleClass="table-detail" layout="grid">
                   <h:outputText value="Group Name" />
                   <h:outputText value=":" />
                   <h:outputText value="#{balance.accountGroupName}" />

                   <h:outputText value="Registration Time" />
                   <h:outputText value=":" />
                   <h:outputText value="#{balance.registrationTimestamp}">
                       <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{web.timestampOutputFormat}" locale="#{web.locale}"
                                          timeZone="#{web.timeZone}" />
                   </h:outputText>

                   <h:outputText value="CoA Type" />
                   <h:outputText value=":" />
                   <h:outputText value="#{balance.coaType}" />

                   <h:outputText value="Bank Name" />
                   <h:outputText value=":" />
                   <h:outputText value="#{balance.bankName}" />

                   <h:outputText value="Bank Account" />
                   <h:outputText value=":" />
                   <h:outputText value="#{balance.bankAccount}" />
               </p:panelGrid>
           </p:rowExpansion>
       </p:dataTable>
       <p:commandButton value="Download"
                        style="float: right;margin-top: 20px;"
                        update=":downloadDialogForm"
                        onclick="PF('downloadDialog').show();"/>
   </h:form>
   ```
2. show results in datatable
3. delete filtering from input text
   [block word and delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJYJk.png)
4. reload data in dataTable and call ajax twice

[after delete, call ajax twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAXYU.png)

how to disable call ajax twice after delete filtering?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (add code as text, not as images)

Comment: @JasperdeVries I edited my question. The image is just a process when I tested the app and the result you can see in the image I attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to resolve this behaviour.(call ajax twice)

1. i checked how this issue resolved on primefaces github(https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/28d558539f323c342396bbf26af0d93a87c2c146?diff=unified)
2. I override the default method with this code(put the code in main template)

> 

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.bindFilterEvent = function(filter) {
                var $this = this;
                //prevent form submit on enter key
                filter.on('keydown.dataTable-blockenter', function(e) {
                    var key = e.which,
                    keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
                    if((key === keyCode.ENTER||key === keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER)) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                })
                .on(this.cfg.filterEvent + '.dataTable', function(e) {
                    var key = e.which,
                    keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
                    ignoredKeys = [keyCode.END, keyCode.HOME, keyCode.LEFT, keyCode.RIGHT, keyCode.UP, keyCode.DOWN,
                        keyCode.TAB, 16/*Shift*/, 17/*Ctrl*/, 18/*Alt*/, 91, 92, 93/*left/right Win/Cmd*/,
                        keyCode.ESCAPE, keyCode.PAGE_UP, keyCode.PAGE_DOWN,
                        19/*pause/break*/, 20/*caps lock*/, 44/*print screen*/, 144/*num lock*/, 145/*scroll lock*/];
                    if (ignoredKeys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if($this.filterTimeout) {
                        clearTimeout($this.filterTimeout);
                    }
                    $this.filterTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        $this.filter();
                        $this.filterTimeout = null;
                    },
                    $this.cfg.filterDelay);
                });

                // #89 IE clear "x" button
                if (PrimeFaces.env.isIE()) {
                    filter.on('mouseup.dataTable', function(e) {
                        var input = $(this),
                        oldValue = input.val();

                        if(oldValue == "") {
                            return;
                        }

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var newValue = input.val();
                            if(newValue == "") {
                                $this.filter();
                            }
                        }, 1);
                    }); 
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Hope this help other